# CSS IE conditional background

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I have a background that I would like to change depending on which browser the user if using. If the user is using IE7 or IE8 I would like to change the background to a totally different image.

Can this be achieved by editing the CSS below as it seems pointless to create a new stylesheet for one item.

Thanks in advance for any help.

```
.navigation{
    background: url("images/navigation.png") no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty sure there's no way to do it without extra markup.

You could just do this in the HTML:

```
<!--[if gte IE7]>
<style type="text/css">
    .navigation{
        background: url("images/navigation.png") no-repeat;
    }
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

Isn't exactly the sexiest bit of code I've ever written, but it does the job without adding a whole separate stylesheet file. Though you might as well give in and make an `iehacks.css` file.

Answer (score 0):

This code should only select the background if you're using IE 7 or greater. Other ways of using conditional HTML can be found at http://css-tricks.com/132-how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/.

```
<!--[if gte IE 7]>
    <style type="text/css">
        .navigation{
            background: url("images/navigation.png") no-repeat;
        }

    </style>
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<body onload="setBG()">
<h1>Welcome to my page</h1>

<script>
function setBG(){
document.body.style.backgroundImage=((!!document.all || window.opera) ? 'w3bg.jpg : 'iebg.jpg') // delete the second ! and switch the jpgs
return
}

</script>
```

This means if the browser does not support document.all (which is supported only in IE4+) or is Opera then display the background iamge w3bg.jpg. If the browser does support document.all then display the background image iebg.jpg.

Answer (score 0):

There is but keep in mind **this is not valid CSS**.  Your best bet is to create the second stylesheet with a conditional statement.

IE7 will interpret this

```
*+html .navigation { background: url("images/navigation.png") no-repeat; }
```

IE8 will interpret this

```
@media \0screen {
  .navigation { background: url("images/navigation2.png") no-repeat; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.navigation{
background: url("images/navigation.png") no-repeat;
/*all browsers*/
}
*+html .navigation {
background: url("images/navigation_onlyIE7.png") no-repeat;
/*only IE7 valid css*/
}
@media \0screen { .navigation
background: url("images/navigation_onlyIE8.png") no-repeat;
/*only IE8 NOT valid css*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would probably use IE CSS hacks that target the element: http://paulirish.com/2009/browser-specific-css-hacks/. It eliminates the need to create a new style sheet.